# issue with choice.exe in windows 10

Tags: batch-file, plsql, windows-10, oracleforms

I integrated two softwares via batch file, everything is working fine in windows 7 but I am not sure why in window 10 my code doesn't function properly, my suspension is due to choice but it is available in system32 folder.

My windows is 10 enterprise and my windows 7 is professional.

I attached part of my code and output.

*I am using oracle form 6i and database 9i.
** code is working fine in windows xp and 7.

Please help me to identify what is wrong with my code in windows 10.

[image]
[image: running code in window 7]

[image: running code in window 10]

[image]

part of code[this code generate in plsql backend and send to oracle form and then write in a batch file and then execute:

```
  LV_SCRIPT :=  LV_SCRIPT || 'pause'|| crlf;

  LV_SCRIPT :=  LV_SCRIPT || 'for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('||'''findstr /c:%Loc% %TEMP%\GET_COPY_PVCS.txt'||''') do ('||crlf;
  LV_SCRIPT :=  LV_SCRIPT || '@echo . . .&& @echo. '|| crlf;
  LV_SCRIPT :=  LV_SCRIPT || '@echo %%i '|| crlf;
  LV_SCRIPT :=  LV_SCRIPT || '@echo.'|| crlf;
  LV_SCRIPT :=  LV_SCRIPT || '@echo Option 1: Checkin object'|| crlf;
  LV_SCRIPT :=  LV_SCRIPT || '@echo Option 2: Update Version Label for PVCS copy' || crlf;
  LV_SCRIPT :=  LV_SCRIPT || '@echo.'|| crlf;


  --LV_SCRIPT :=    LV_SCRIPT || '@CHOICE /C 12N /M "Select a for option 1 and option 2 or N for No:"' || crlf;

  LV_SCRIPT :=  LV_SCRIPT || 'if "%version%" == "6" @CHOICE /C 12N /M "Select a for option 1 and option 2 or N for No:"' || crlf;---pvcs2
  LV_SCRIPT :=  LV_SCRIPT || 'if "%version%" == "5" @CHOICE /C12N "Select a for option 1 and option 2 or N for No:"' || crlf;---pvcs2

  LV_SCRIPT :=  LV_SCRIPT || 'if !errorlevel! equ 1 call :Checkin "%%i"' || crlf;
  LV_SCRIPT :=  LV_SCRIPT || 'if !errorlevel! equ 2 call :VersionLabel "%%i"'|| crlf;
  LV_SCRIPT :=  LV_SCRIPT || ')' || crlf;
  LV_SCRIPT :=  LV_SCRIPT || '@endlocal' || crlf;
  LV_SCRIPT :=  LV_SCRIPT || 'pause' || crlf;
  LV_SCRIPT :=  LV_SCRIPT || 'exit' || crlf;
```

Oracle form code:

```
lv_userfile:= lv_userfile ||'GET_COPY_PVCS.bat';
                        LV_CONTENT := bpg_gen.BFN_GET_COPY_PVCS(:CMMT_FIX_MASTER.V_FIX_LOC,lv_userfile,LV_LOCATION,:CMMT_OBJECTS.V_OBJECT_NAME,:CMMT_OBJECTS.V_TYPE,:CMMT_FIX_MASTER.V_CUSTOMER);--PV_FIX_LOC VARCHAR2,PV_BatchLocation VARCHAR2,PV_PVCSLOC VARCHAR2,PV_OBJECTNAME VARCHAR2

                        out_file := text_IO.fopen(lv_userfile,'w');

                        text_IO.put (out_file,LV_CONTENT);
                        text_IO.new_line(out_file);

                        text_IO.fclose(out_file);

                        Host('cmd /c start '||lv_userfile);
```

Comment: Have you checked the value in `%version%`?

Comment: That could be a good point, I guess that is the issue